# Having troubles with react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm following this YouTube tutorial from JavaBrains
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4iM7eEl3Rag&list=PLqq-6Pq4lTTa8V613TZhGq4o8hSgkMGQ0&index=9&t=292s

Everything goes smooth and well until he implements the BrowserRouter. The thing is that I copy exactly what he's doing but unfortunately I get a blank page, not matter what I change it's still blank. Any ideas how to solve it? I have asked also in the channel but with no answer. Thanks!
The url will be: localhost:3000/teams/xxx

This is the piece of code of App.js

```
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { TeamPage } from './pages/TeamPage';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Route path="/teams/:teamName">
          <TeamPage />
        </Route>
      </Router>
    </div>
  ); 
}

export default App;
```

and this is the TeamPage.js

```
import { React, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { MatchDetailCard } from "../components/MatchDetailCard";
import { MatchSmallCard } from "../components/MatchSmallCard";

export const TeamPage = () => {

  const [team, setTeam] = useState({ matches: [] });
  const { teamName } = useParams();

  useEffect(
    () => {
      const fetchMatches = async () => {
        const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:8080/api/team/${teamName}`);
        const data = await response.json();
        setTeam(data);
      };
      fetchMatches();
    }, [teamName] //This empty array as a second argument tells: Call useEffect only when something inside change
  );

  if(!team || !team.teamName) {
    return <h1>Team Not Found</h1>
  }

  return (
    <div className="TeamPage">
      <h1>{team.teamName}</h1>

      <MatchDetailCard teamName={team.teamName} match={team.matches[0]} />
      {team.matches.slice(1).map((match) => 
        <MatchSmallCard teamName={team.teamName} match={match} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default TeamPage;
```

Hope you can help meee!!!

Comment: A lot of RRD tutorials have become outdated after the release of `react-router-dom@6`. What version do you have installed locally? From your project directory please run `npm list react-router-dom` and report back. I suspect you just need to use the v6 APIs.

Comment: Hello Drew, I'm using react-router-dom@6.2.1. What should I do? I've seen that the tutorial is using @5.2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `react-router-dom@6` the API changed quite a bit. `Route` components ***must*** be rendered by a `Routes` component (*it's like the v5 `Switch`*) and the routed components are rendered via an `element` prop that takes a `ReactElement`, a.k.a. JSX.

Example:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { TeamPage } from './pages/TeamPage';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/teams/:teamName" element={<TeamPage />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  ); 
}
```

Comment: I've tried that and also downgrading the router-dom@5.2.0 and still does not work. Im frustrated!

Comment: @user3047319 Routing and rendering a page appears to work as expected in this [codesandboc](https://codesandbox.io/s/having-troubles-with-react-router-dom-kxlm0h?file=/src/App.js). Are you seeing any errors? What issues are you seeing with your code? Think you could fork this sandbox, or create one of your own, that reproduces any issues you have that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: Thanks Drew! I've resolved by creating the react-app again and when adding the router, I've chosen the @5.2.0 version, which is used in the tutorial and it worked!

Comment: @user3047319 Ok, glad to assist. Cheers and good luck!